# Ninja Framework JSR303Validation in Filter

Tags: java, validation, filter, ninjaframework

I'm working on a Ninja JSON-based application in which I am implementing @JSR303Validation annotations across multiple controller methods. I'm currently checking validations in the controllers themselves by passing in the Validation object and calling `validation.hasBeanViolations()` to see if there are failures. If there are, I'm returning a failing Result to the client.

Rather than doing this in the controller, I would like to validate requests using a Filter. However, I'm at a loss as to how to go about doing this? Could somebody help? As far as I can tell, you can't pass validations to a filter as a parameter, and the context.getValidation() object does not seem to be catching any validation failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently not possible using a Filter (as of Ninja 4.0.x). However, you can implement it yourself. That would work roughly the following way:

- Create the filter
- Get the contents of the incoming request via
  `context.getParameterAs("parametername", Pojo.class);`
- Validate the class yourself using `javax.validation.Validation`. You can more or less copy and paste the approach from JSRValidator  (https://github.com/ninjaframework/ninja/blob/develop/ninja-core/src/main/java/ninja/validation/Validators.java).

That's not too complicated. But it's not as automagic as annotating methods in the controllers.